# Codeigniter: Set 'global variable'

Tags: session, codeigniter, variables

If I want to set a variable that my whole controller can access, how do I do it?

Right now, in every function I am setting

```
$id = $this->session->userdata('id');
```

I'd like to be able to access $id from any function w/o defining it for each controller. :)

If there's a better way, I'm all ears! I'm a noob!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To elaborate on [Koo5's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408482/codeigniter-set-global-variable/3408696#3408696), you'll want to do something like this:

```
class yourController extends Controller {

    // this is a property, accessible from any function in this class
    public $id = null;

    // this is the constructor (mentioned by Koo5)
    function __construct() {
        // this is how you reference $id within the class
        $this->id = $this->session->userdata('id');
    }

    function getID() {
        // returning the $id property
        return $this->id;
    }

}
```

See the manual for more information on PHP [properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) and [constructors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php). Hope that helps!

Comment: You saved me again, Colin.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If with **global** you mean the scope of a single controller, the above answers are correct. If you want to access variables from multiple controllers, I recommend defining a BaseController class and then extending your normal controllers to inherit from that BaseController:

```
class yourController extends BaseController {}
```

I use this all the time for both global variables and methods.

Answer (score 0):

Define that very line in a constructor only

Comment: I get "Undefined variable".  Could you give more information?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method too inside your controller

```
function __construct() {
    // this is how you reference $id within the class
    DEFINE("userId",$this->session->userdata('id'));
}
```

And Call It As  :

```
function getID() {
    // returning the $id property
    return userId;
}
```